# Match ids and print original file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have two files

Original: (5000 entries)

```
Chr Position
chr1    879108
chr1    881918
chr1    896874
…
```

and a file with allele frequencies (2000 entries)

```
Chr Position MAF
chr1 881918  0.007   
chr1 979748  0.007   
chr1 1120377 0.007  
chr1 1178925 0.036
```

I would like the original file matched with the allele frequencies and print out the output file with 5000 entries. Can this be done with awk or sed?

```
Chr Position MAF
chr1    879108
chr1    881918 0.007
chr1    896874
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1,$2]=$3; next} {$3=A[$1,$2]}1' file2 file
```

Answer (score 2):

I could obtain what you need using `join` and `awk`

```
$ cat original 
chr1    879108
chr1    881918
chr1    896874
$ cat freq 
chr1 881918  0.007   
chr1 979748  0.007   
chr1 1120377 0.007  
chr1 1178925 0.036 
$ join -a1 -j 2 --nocheck-order original freq | awk '{print $2, $1, $4}'
chr1 879108 
chr1 881918 0.007
chr1 896874
```

Where `-a1` means to print all lines of the first file, `-j 2` matches on the second field, and `--nocheck-order` does not check the sorted input. The pipe to `awk` is just to process the columns to a shape that you need.

Comment: Be aware that "join" assumes that the input files are already sorted on the join-field.

Comment: After sorting, run: `join -a1 -a2 -j2 -o 0,2.1,2.3 original freq` ... Note: The sorting must be text sort, not numerical sort.

Comment: @Johan I assumed that the second column was already sorted nicely numerically. Then there is no need to sort again, or check for sorting by `join`. Therefor I added the `--nocheck-order` flag. I am not familiar with the `-o` flag for output control, but apparently it is possible to skip the `awk`-step here. Thanks for this addition.

Comment: And I wasn't familiar with the nocheck-order flag, which is apparently needed because the input is not sorted in the way join likes it.

Comment: Also possibly worth mentioning ... sorting will deal fairly well with the blank lines in the OP's sample input files, particularly `sort -u`